# Change text based on parameter within link - ex. welcome message with name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with creating simple script.
I'm trying to trigger text change when user click specially prepared link.

I'm sending to my friends via email or messenger link to website with our tournaments. 
On this website I want to welcome them by custom message. 
But each of them have separate link like:

www.mywebsite.com/#john1
www.mywebsite.com/#john2

So when ex. one of them access website via link:

www.mywebsite.com/#john1

I want to display custom message for him. Custom title.
But when other friends access website via link:

www.mywebsite.com

Everything will be default. No change is needed to this title.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

I tried to achieve something like onclick event with jquery. Set there text for all of this and than access them via mywebsite.com/#john1 etc
But looks like this is a bad idea because this doesn't work when add parameter to link.
Only when click element on website.

I tried something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#john1, #john2").on("click", function(e) {
        var txt = "";
        switch ($(this).prop("id")) {
            case "john1":
                txt = "Hi john 1";
                break;
            case "john2":
                txt = "Hi John 2";
                break;
        }
        $("#h1-title").text(txt);
    })
})
```

and than access like: www.mywebsite.com/#john2

But I know this isn't good use case for that.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but you can check the current link using ‘window.location.pathname’, and then do whatever action you want depending on the current value.

Comment: @AhmedHammad thanks for message. Sorry if you couldn't understand it. I fixed my question and hope now this is clear.
I looked your suggestion with window .location.pathname but honestly have no idea how this can help me solve my problem.
I want like up to 10 custom messages so my buddies can access website with custom information separate for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you are trying to do is to have a customized greeting message for every visitor you send him a customized URL, but show no message for the ordinary URL.

This can be done as follows:

1. Define the format of the customized URL. `www.mywebsite.com#john1` looks so fine. (Note that there is not slash before the hash! It's not a sub-directory.
2. Have a function that determines the name of the visitor:

```
function getVisitorName(){
    let name = window.location.href;
    let indexOfHash = name.indexOf('#');
    if(indexOfHash === -1){return null;}
    name = name.slice(indexOfHash+1, name.length)
    return name;
  }
```

3. Now, call this function upon the event you like. (Page load for example):

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    let name = getVisitorName;
    if (name === null) {return;}
    let message = "Hi " + name + " !";
    $("#h1-title").text(message);
  })
```

4. Send links to your friends customized as `www.mywebsite.com#John1`, `www.mywebsite.com#John2`..etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for solution but I have a problem with it.

But all the time slash is being added before hash. 

Plus when I tried to test it I'm getting getVisitorName function inside my title instead of custom message.

I have jquery declared without issue because Im using other custom stuff and all works well. Plus code is declared inside my one custom js file.

Comment: I forgot to add, that I'm testing this on local with Mamp

Comment: 1- Slashes won’t work here. Slashes are part of the URL semantics, telling the browser to go into another sub-page, which is not the case here.

Comment: 2- what do you mean by “I’m getting getVisitorName function inside my title instead of custom message”? You may be not calling the function in a right way?

Comment: Yes I understand slashes won't work. But in this case slash is included all the time. When I'm trying to access this via localhost/website#john I'm getting this in browser: localhost/website/#john
About getting functions is that this doesn't work for me. I tried to put all together and I can not get this code to work. Always in a place of title this display me whole visitor function as a title.